# How to close modal in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-modalbox.

I want to open the ScreenB from the ScreenA.

and I want to close ScreenA after ScreenB open.

Anyone know how to solve it?

```
import Modal from 'react-native-modalbox';
import ScreenB from './ScreenB';

class ScreenA extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Modal
                ref={"modal1"}
                swipeToClose={true}
                coverScreen={true}
            ><ScreenB></ScreenB>
            </Modal>
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this.refs.modal1.open()}>
                    <Text>Click me</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
/*********/ 
$<Modal transparent={true} visible={ this.props.loading }
                   onRequestClose={() => {this._setModalVisible(false)}}>
                    {loading}
            </Modal>

 _setModalVisible(visible) {
        this.setState({loading: visible})
    }$
/***********/
```

Answer (score 0):

You looks using the modal way to show new page. It is different with replacing to a new page. Normally, modal is using to show a temporary page.

If you want to change the page from a to b and closing a, it will be better to use [ReactNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack)
 or [React Native Router](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux). Then, find replace options with modal animation.